# UK Transit Visa Required or Not - Travel to US via a stop in the Schengen zone

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am traveling from Mumbai-Heathrow-Oslo-Heathrow-NewYork-Heathrow-Mumbai on 28th May. I have a valid Schengen Visa and USA visa.

For the Mum-Heathrow-Oslo (staying in Oslo for 10 days) leg I have a stop over for 1 hour 20 minutes and on the same terminal. Just need to change my flight.

As per UK visa rules if your destination or source is USA (which I have since my last destination is USA) then you don't require UK transit visa.

In my case would I require UK transit visa. I don't have time for it since my passport is coming from Norway embassy tomorrow and I have to travel on 28th May. (Sat-Sun falls in between).

Can someone please help me.

Comment: I think you're going to have to ring the British Consulate and ask. The [UK Border Agency visa wizard](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/) isn't clear on if the stopover in Oslo on your way to America still qualifies you for the *Transit Without Visa Exemption* or not (you'd be fine if you didn't stop in Norway)

Comment: Unconfirmed answer 1 in question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/uk-transit-visa-from-usa-to-india

Comment: More then likely you will need a transit visa since you will be coming from Oslo to New York via Heathrow.  https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=NO&EM=IN&TR=GB&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#

Comment: What passport are you on? Indian? It can make a difference.