# Do I need a Direct Air Transit Visa or Visitor in Transit Visa for the UK?

Tags: transit, uk, layovers, datv

I am traveling from the United States to India via British Airways with a 4 hour layover in London. My current H1-B visa has expired, but I have the approval for my extension 
(I-797) and I plan to get the visa stamped in India.

- Do I need a Direct Air Transit Visa (DATV) or a Visitor in Transit Visa.
- Is there a list for the detailed procedure to apply for the relevant Visa.
- Can I give and collect the passport in person from the consulate?

Comment: When was the last time you entered the US? If it's [less that 6 months ago](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no), you won't need a visa.

Comment: Related to [UK Transit Visa from USA to India](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/uk-transit-visa-from-usa-to-india?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

In general, Indian citizens do need a direct airside transit visa in this scenario. But you might be exempted based either on your visa (if you entered less than 6 months ago) or on the I-797 (but there are different types of I-797 so it's a little confusing). See [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no).

If you don't need to pass through UK immigration (e.g. to switch airports or collect your luggage), you don't need a visitor in transit visa. For a 4-hour layover with only one airline, I assume it's your case.

Since the airline will decide if you can board the plane or not, you might want to contact them to ask what their rules are.